# Panresponder with ternary operator

Tags: react-native

Have this structure of code:

```
///
this.state.condition ? (
  <View {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}>
    child
  </View>
) : (<View></View>)
///
```

The problem is that panhandlers stay active for another View element in ternary operator which is without assigned panResponder.
Maybe it happens because of react 'Nodes' handling in React-Native renderer.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping View element with responder via another View solved this issue.